# How do I get my sim7600E with a esp32 to connect to the internet?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I am using the T-SIM7600E-L1C 4G LTE ESP32 from TTGO, My problem is that it won't connect to the internet? Here is the code that I am using.

```
 // Arduino file start here
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7600
#define SerialMon Serial
//#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon
#include <HCSR04.h>
#define SOUND_SPEED 0.034
#define CM_TO_INCH 0.393701
HardwareSerial SerialAT(1);

#if !defined(TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER)
#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER 650
#endif
#define TINY_GSM_YIELD() { delay(2); }
const char apn[]  = "Vodacom APN"; 
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";
const char server[] = ""; 
const char resource[] = "";
const int  port = 80;
unsigned long timeout;

const int trigPin = 25;  
const int echoPin = 26; 
long duration;
int distance;
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>

TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
TinyGsmClient client(modem);

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  
  SerialMon.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  SerialMon.println("Wait...");
  SerialAT.begin(115200,SERIAL_8N1,26,27, false);
  delay(600);
  SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
}

void loop()
 {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

  modem.restart();
  SerialMon.print("Waiting for network...");
  if (!modem.waitForNetwork()) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(1000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");
  if (modem.isNetworkConnected()) 
  {
    SerialMon.println("Network connected");
  }

  SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
  SerialMon.print(apn);
  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) 
  {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(1000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (modem.isGprsConnected()) 
  {
    SerialMon.println("GPRS connected");
  }

  if (!client.connect(server, port))
   {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
   }
  SerialMon.println("Performing HTTP POST request...");
  String httpRequestData = "key=a@4K%3&distance="+ String(distance) +"";
  client.print(String("POST ") + resource + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  client.print(String("Host: ") + server + "\r\n");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  client.print("Content-Length: ");
  client.println(httpRequestData.length());
  client.println();
  client.println(httpRequestData);
  timeout = millis();
  while (client.connected() && millis() - timeout < 10000L)
   {
    while (client.available())
     {
      char c = client.read();
      SerialMon.print(c);
      timeout = millis();
     }
  }
  SerialMon.println();
  client.stop();
  SerialMon.println(F("Server disconnected"));
  modem.gprsDisconnect();
  SerialMon.println(F("GPRS disconnected"));
}
```

The fail message:

```
et.Rչ� 8�016 0�'&&��SH�HH���0� (POWE���%UMQ�,boot:�� (DO���} =OT(UAR�UART1iE%=}I%�REO_V2JJC�W�ѥng for"�ݹ����5ets Jun 8 2016 00:22:57rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xeeclk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00mode:DIO, clock div:1load:0x3fff0018,len:4load:0x3fff001c,len:1216ho 0 tail 12 room 4load:0x40078000,len:9720ho 0 tail 12 room 4load:0x40080400,len:6352entry 0x400806b8Wait
...Initializing modem
...Waiting for network
...fail
```

Comment: without the TinyGSM library it connects?

Comment: I am not sure how to test that ?

Comment: with AT commands.

Comment: Will see if I can get the correct commands and then give feed back

Answer (score 0):

Exists a lot of problems with mobile that you need to verify when you use an internet modem in your Arduino project. The problems involve for example, the lack of current (you need to give 2A of current to work properly), the dupont cables/jumpers couldn't work sometimes (the connection cables need to be short), and the APN, when I worked with this kind of SIMCOM modems I needed to buy a telemetry SIM card too.

Comment: Thank you for your response,I did a few AT command tests and found that the module gives me an output of 18/99 when running the Signal quality comand not sure why but it seems that the module is not connecting to the network because it does not get signal or it doesn't use the sim card correctly. Not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't sure about this problem, but I believe that you need to try another SIM card. When I worked with Simcom devices I had to use a m2m card to work properly.